# Hoare Triples - Weakest Precondition / Strongest Postcondition

Tags: formal-verification, formal-methods, hoare-logic

Is this correct, for weakest pre-condition respectively strongest post-condition?

{P} x = x-x; {x'=x}
P: x = 0

{true} y = y-y; {Q}
Q: y = 0

Edit:

I started by applying [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics#Strongest_postcondition) as follows:

{true} y = y - y {Q} ==> sp(y = y-y; true) = ∃x,y = x-x ∧ true

Now I'm not sure what to do with this; In my mind "y = 0" would make most sense, but that doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

The stronger is the precondition, the stronger is the postcondition. For example,

```
{y = 5} x := 8 {x = 8; y = 5}
```

If the precondition is the weakest one instead, i.e. `true`, there are no valid assumptions about the value of `y` in the postcondition.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; does that mean we can't define a valid strongest post-condition? Because I'm pretty sure there *is* a valid answer to find.

Comment: The strongest postcondition for the weakest precondition `true` is `x = 8`. However, if the precondition is stronger, e.g. `y = 5`, the postcondition is stronger as well.